# How to select an attribute from filters?

Tags: siddhi

I have a query written as -

```
from xyzStream [str:contains(name,'John') or str:contains(name,'Peter')  or str:contains(name,'Sandy') ]
select name 
insert into outputStream
```

but now i want to make an enhancement where i pass the filter substring that matched. Like for example if str:contains(name,'John') returns true, insert 'John' in output stream.

Is there a way to do it in SiddhiQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, this is not supported, however you can do the same in the select clause with str:contains and ifthenElse,

```
from xyzStream [str:contains(name,'John') or str:contains(name,'Peter')  or str:contains(name,'Sandy') ]
select name, 
    ifthenElse(str:contains('John'), 'John', ifThenElse(str:contains('Peter'), 'Peter', 'Sandy')) as matchedString
insert into outputStream
```

See [example](https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/examples/if-then-else/) on ifThenElse function for more details